# OpenCV 3.2.0, Visual Studio 2015, Windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I installed the pre-built libraries OpenCV 3.2.0 on Windows 7 following the [instructions here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d6/d8a/tutorial_windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html) and I am encountering errors when trying to use them in Visual Studio 2015.

The variable `OPENCV_DIR` is set correctly:

```
C:\>echo %OPENCV_DIR%
C:\OpenCV\Build\x64\vc14

C:\>dir %OPENCV_DIR%
 Le volume dans le lecteur C s'appelle OS
 Le numéro de série du volume est 1234-ABCD

 Répertoire de C:\OpenCV\Build\x64\vc14

27/01/2017  17:10    <REP>          .
27/01/2017  17:10    <REP>          ..
27/01/2017  17:11    <REP>          bin
27/01/2017  17:10    <REP>          lib
               0 fichier(s)                0 octets
               4 Rép(s)  19 236 450 304 octets libres

C:\>
```

And the rules for the project are like there

[image]

[image]

With the libraries specified as

[image]

```
opencv_calib3d320d.lib
opencv_core320d.lib
opencv_features2d320d.lib
opencv_flann320d.lib
opencv_highgui320d.lib
opencv_imgcodecs320d.lib
opencv_imgproc320d.lib
opencv_ml320d.lib
opencv_objdetect320d.lib
opencv_photo320d.lib
opencv_shape320d.lib
opencv_stitching320d.lib
opencv_superres320d.lib
opencv_ts320d.lib
opencv_video320d.lib
opencv_videoio320d.lib
opencv_videostab320d.lib
```

But when I try to compile the basic test project written there

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if( argc != 2)
    {
     cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
     return -1;
    }
    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file
    if( image.empty() ) // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); // Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image ); // Show our image inside it.
    waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ImageCorrection, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  test.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d320d.lib'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am really new to compilation and linking on Windows and Visual Studio (I am used to `g++` on Linux) so I really have *no idea* of what I am doing wrong here.
I think that it might have something to do with the dynamic linking, but I do not know neither how to investigate nor how to solve it.

Ant help is most appreciated! :D

Comment: Prebuilt only have `opencv_world320(d).lib`. That's the only one you need to link

Comment: Indeed... I wonder why in the tutorial is not written anywhere... If you write it as a solution I'll gladly accept it!

Comment: With this kind of problem, it might be worth to look in the directory to see if the files you're trying to link with are actually there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV 3.2 prebuild binaries have just the *world* lib:

- `opencv_world320.lib` for release
- `opencv_world320d.lib` for debug

That's all you need to link.